# DATEDIFF() of Unix Timestamps has NULL results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the number of days between two dates: one column of Unix times and the current timestamp. To do that, I have the following MySQL code:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(synced_on/1000,'%m-%d-%Y') AS synced_on_date,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),
  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%m-%d-%Y'),
  DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(synced_on/1000,'%m-%d-%Y'), FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%m-%d-%Y')) AS datediff,
  DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%m-%d-%Y'), FROM_UNIXTIME(synced_on/1000,'%m-%d-%Y')) AS datediff_two
FROM db.tableA
```

The results look like:

```
synced_on_date  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%m-%d-%Y') datediff    datediff_two
07-24-2022      2022-07-25 17:47:54     07-25-2022      
07-14-2022      2022-07-25 17:47:54     07-25-2022      
07-24-2022      2022-07-25 17:47:54     07-25-2022      
07-24-2022      2022-07-25 17:47:54     07-25-2022      
07-17-2022      2022-07-25 17:47:54     07-25-2022      
07-20-2022      2022-07-25 17:47:54     07-25-2022
```

You'll notice that the `DATEDIFF()` results are null. Any ideas on next steps to address this?

Comment: datediff will be expecting y-m-d, not m-d-y

Comment: do you mean to truncate to day and then calculate the difference in days?  calculating the difference in days between datetimes will produce a different result

Comment: you say "between two columns" but only use one column?

Comment: Good points. Correction: "between one column of Unix times and the current timestamp"

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the number of days between two dates.

Comment: but if the column is 2022-07-24 23:00:00 and it is now 2022-07-26 01:00:00 (26 hours later), you can truncate to date first and get a 2 day difference (this seems to be what you are trying to do, but maybe not intentionally), or you can not truncate and get a 1 day difference.  which do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The code that achieves my goal is:

```
SELECT 
  ROUND( (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - synced_on/1000) / 86400, 0) AS days_since_sync
FROM db.tableA;
```